# Does saying kobul to a male 3 times without parental consent get you married?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, parents

I made a mistake 2 years ago by getting into a relationship with someone. I said kobul to him 3 times without the permission of my parents. We are not together anymore as I've realised that being in a relationship is very much haraam. I ask for forgiveness all the time.

I want to know whether or not we are tied in marriage by saying kobul?

My mother found out about the relationship and made me realise that I went astray and did not approve of him.

Answer (score 1):

No, saying kobul to a male three times without parental consent **does not get you married.** Your marriage with that man is invalid. The Prophet (peace be upon him) said:

> “**Any woman who marries without the permission of her wali, her marriage is
>   invalid**, her marriage is invalid, her marriage is invalid.”
>   (Reported by al-Tirmidhi, 1021; Grade: Sahih)